# iOS: Appending UIButton right next to multilines UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

[image]

I am trying to make UILabel with UIButton (more Info) that appends right next to uilabel in multi-lines UILabel.

As shown in the picture (case 1, 2), if uilabel text is short, and doesn’t exceed multilines restriction (right now numberOfLines set to 4), it will append right next to the label. I have achieved that by setting hugging, and compression.

Also, on the 4th case, uilabel is truncated due to multiline restriction, so it truncates, and appends moreInfo uibutton.

It gets complicated on the 3rd case. When it does not exceed multilines restriction, but over 1 line, more info has to be appended right next to the trailing. but as uilabel width is max position of the 2nd line, i don’t know how to achieve that.
Are there ways to append UIbutton right next to UILabel's last position text? (if uilabel + uibutton exceeds the width of device, the uilabel has to be truncated as well.)

For example,
[image]

Comment: Quick search for `swift add "read more" at the end of a string` comes up with many answers. Have you tried any?

Answer (score 0):

There should be couple of ways to achieve this. Here is a direct one with using constraints. Note that you should set these in your storyboard while this demo shows them in-code so you can read them easier

```
        // A panel to demonstrate the superview constraint
        let panel = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20.0, y: 100.0, width: view.bounds.width-40.0, height: 300.0))
        panel.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        self.view.addSubview(panel)
        
        let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        label.numberOfLines = 4
//        label.text = "Some fairly long text to demonstrate line break but not enough to exceed the number of lines being 4"
        label.text = "Some_fairly_long_text_to demonstrate_line_break_but not_enough_to_exceed_the number_of_lines_being_4"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        panel.addSubview(label)
        
        let button = UIButton(frame: .zero)
        button.setTitle("More info", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        panel.addSubview(button)
        
        button.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
        
        panel.addConstraints([
            .init(item: label, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: panel, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0),
            .init(item: label, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: panel, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0),
            .init(item: button, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .lessThanOrEqual, toItem: panel, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0),
            .init(item: button, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: label, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0),
            .init(item: button, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: label, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0),
            .init(item: label, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .lessThanOrEqual, toItem: button, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        ])
```

At least if I understand correctly this was your issue and the output for iPhone14 Pro looks like this

[image]

You could improve this by also adding some constrain for button height or maybe the whole thing would be easier using a stack view:

```
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [label, button])
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.alignment = .center
    stackView.distribution = .fill
    panel.addSubview(stackView)
    
    panel.addConstraints([
        .init(item: stackView, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: panel, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0),
        .init(item: stackView, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .lessThanOrEqual, toItem: panel, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0),
        .init(item: stackView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: panel, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0),
    ])
```

Doing it this way you can have better control over how button is resized by changing stack view properties. And also label can resize when too small so that your button can define minimum size as well.

Again I would do all of this in a Storyboard. The code is just to explain it easier.

Comment: I don't see how the output should be. It's just saying use stackview and that's it?